# Unity 2D NPC teleports instead of moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and C#, but I'm trying to learn by making a basic RPG. I've gotten to a point, where my player character can move, but when I try to make an NPC walk to a specific point, it just teleports instantly.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Walker : MonoBehaviour

{
    public float walkerSpeed = 1.0f;

    public void moveWalker(float x, float y)
    {
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(x, y) * walkerSpeed;
        movement *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        transform.Translate(movement);
    }

    public void ScriptedWalk(float MoveToX, float MoveToY)
    {
        while (Mathf.Abs(MoveToX - transform.position.x) > 0.05f)
            if (MoveToX > transform.position.x)
                moveWalker(1, 0);
            else
                moveWalker(-1, 0);
    }

}
```

I'm calling `ScriptedWalk` from my NPC's Start function, and I got stuck testing movement on the x axis. The NPC is in X = -2.5 and neds to get to X = 2.
What am I not understanding here?

Comment: You shouldn't use while loop in game loop. Your while loop is stopping the main loop (Update) from Unity. When you stop the main game loop, you freeze your frames. If you want a smooth animation transform, try wrap it in a Coroutine
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Douglas, as you've suggested in your comment, I used a Coroutine, and changed my `ScriptedWalk` to this:

```
public IEnumerator ScriptedWalk(float MoveToX, float MoveToY)
{
    if (Mathf.Abs(MoveToX - transform.position.x) < 0.05f)
    {
        // set animator floats to 0
        stopWalker();
    }
    else
    {
        // Move east
        if (MoveToX > transform.position.x)
            moveWalker(1, 0);
        // Move west
        else
            moveWalker(-1, 0);
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

I am also calling it from my `FixedUpdate` method.